# How to show private inheritance relationship in a UML class diagram

Tags: c++, inheritance, uml, class-diagram

In C++ since private inheritance is not considered as an `is-a` relationship, how is it supposed to be shown in a class diagram and if it is shown as a `has-a` relationship then how can it be differentiated between a composition and a private inheritance?

Comment: This is an excellent question. The problem is that private inheritance is an oxymoron, which is why it is not part of the UML dictionary. I would show it as has-a with a remark stating that it's privately inherited. Another choice is to refactor your design to avoid private inheritance: the cases when you must have it are few and far between, so good chances are that a plain has-a would work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

It should be a Composition relationship (solid black diamond on the subclass side), because:

- Private inheritance means "implemented in terms of" but in this regard it can be simply treated the same as "has a" relationship.
- An instance of the subclass clearly owns the base calss part of the object, and the ownership is not shared with any other objects.