# What is the relationship corresponding to implementation inheritance in UML?

Tags: inheritance, uml, class-diagram, notation

What is the relationship corresponding to *implementation inheritance* (realized with private inheritance in C++) in the current [UML specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) (2.5.1, December 2017)?

Not to be confused with *interface inheritance* (subtyping) which corresponds in UML to the *interface realization* relationship denoted by a dashed line and hollow triangle, nor with *implementation and interface inheritance* (subclassing) which corresponds in UML to the *generalization* relationship denoted by a solid line and hollow triangle.

*Note.* — The book *Design Patterns* by Erich Gamma et al. published in 1994 (before UML) whose class diagrams are based on OMT (an ancestor of UML) used informally a solid line and hollow triangle with an “(implementation)” modifier for denoting implementation inheritance:

[image: Class adapter]

Figure. — OMT class diagram of the class Adapter design pattern.

Comment: I think that's just coding stuff and not part of UML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774204/difference-between-interface-inheritance-and-implementation-inheritance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GoF terminology

GoF proposes some terminology (p. 13-15) which you seem to have adopted:

- an ***object*** packages data (its *state*) and procedures (its *methods*) that are the only way to access the data (*state encapsulation*).
- the ***interface*** to an object is the set of its methods’ signatures.
- a ***type*** is the name of a particular interface.
- a ***subtype*** is a type that is a superset of another type.
- a ***supertype*** is a type that is a subset of another type.
- the ***implementation*** of an object is the set of its state and methods’ implementations.
- a ***class*** defines an object’s interface and implementation.
- a ***subclass*** defines a class that is a superset of another class.
- a ***superclass*** defines a class that is a subset of another class.
- ***inheritance*** in this understanding corresponds to reusing an implementation.

This understanding is driven by reuse, the main topic of their book: types are just reuse of an interface, whereas classes are reuse of an implementation. This view is reductionist:

- Nothing is said about the promises and expectations behind an interface (e.g. that I can only `pop()` from the stack if I have `push()`ed something on it first). It is just about the ability to accept the requests defined by the interface.
- The distinction between an abstract class (which defines an interface without providing an implementation) and an interface is not at all clarified.

The last point is perfectly illustrated in your graphical example.

- In the GoF narrative, `Target` and `Adaptee` are both defined as interface (see p. 141, section "participants"), whereas `Adapter` implements these interfaces.
- Yet, in the schema, `Target` is represented as an abstract class (see p. 365) and `Adapter`’s `Request()` is implemented by calling `SpecificRequest()` but it is not shown that `Adapter` must implement `SpecificRequest()` as well.
- Finally, GoF explains that `Adapter` is a subclass of `Adaptee`, which seems somewhat inconsistent.

### UML perspective

The UML definition of an interface is much closer to what [Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) would call a type:

> An **Interface** […] represents a declaration of a set of public Features and obligations that together constitute a **coherent service**. An Interface specifies a contract […]. The obligations associated with an Interface are in the form of constraints (such as pre- and postconditions) or protocol specifications, which may impose ordering restrictions on interactions through the Interface. Interfaces may not be instantiated. Instead, an Interface specification is implemented or realized […].

Classes define sets of features, may implement interfaces and can be instantiated.

What you call *interface inheritance* is ambiguous:

- If you mean a class that implements the interface, it is interface realization, denoted by a dotted line with a hollow triangle on the side of the interface to be realized.
- If you mean an interface that inherits another interface (subtyping), it is interface specialization, denoted by a plain line with a hollow triangle on the side of the more general interface.

What you call *implementation and interface inheritance* is ambiguous, since it is not clear if *inheritance* applies only to *interface* or also to *implementation*:

- If you mean the implementation of an existing interface with a class, it is interface realization with a dotted line with a hollow triangle on the side of the interface to be realized.
- If you mean the simultaneous inheritance of both an interface and their implementation, then it is class specialization, denoted by a plain line with a hollow triangle on the side of the more general class.

If with *implementation inheritance* you were thinking of inheriting the implementation without inheriting the interface, i.e. private inheritance, then there is nothing special foreseen in UML, and you have to translate your implementation intent into UML concepts, as explained for example in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9415350/3723423).

Now to illustrate the graphical notation, here is the class Adapter pattern as described in GoF using the participant roles:

[image]

And here is a more logic diagram, if considering that `Adaptee` is in reality an existing implementation that needs to be adapted:

[image]

Comment: I was puzzled when reading the term _implementation inheritance_ and googled it (just to find that it seems to be used in the Java world). Looks like I'm not the only one not geting a grip on that.

Comment: Thanks Chris! So the bottom line is that there is no equivalent UML relationship for private inheritance.

Comment: 1. Let me make a few remarks: 1. "inheritance in this understanding corresponds to reusing or redefining an implementation." GoF does not restrict inheritance to implementation inheritance: "It’s also important to understand the difference between class inheritance and interface inheritance (or subtyping). Class inheritance defines an object’s implementation in terms of another object’s implementation. In short, it’s a mechanism for code and representation sharing. In contrast, interface inherence (or subtyping) describes when an object can be used in place of another." (cf. p. 17).

Comment: 2. "Nothing is said about the promises and expectations behind an interface." I agree, GoF does not use Barbara Liskov’s [behavioural types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_subtyping) (types with semantic *specifications*, such as preconditions, postconditions, invariants and the history rule). Their types are purely syntactical.

Comment: 3. "The distinction between an abstract class (which defines an interface without providing an implementation) and an interface is not at all clarified." GoF defines a class as a means to provide an object’s interface and implementation (its state and the set of its operations’ implementations). And GoF defines an abstract class as a class that cannot be instantiated. So the difference is there: an abstract class can provide an implementation, so it is not a pure interface.

Comment: 4. "In the GoF narrative, Target and Adaptee are both defined as interface (see p. 141, section "participants"), whereas Adapter implements these interfaces." Even concrete class have an interface, so GoF does not define Adaptee "as an interface" (meaning a pure interface), but as a "concrete class" (cf. p. 142) which "defines an existing interface" (cf. p. 141).

Comment: 5. "Yet, in the schema, Target is represented as an abstract class (see p. 365) and Adapter’s Request() is implemented by calling SpecificRequest() but it is not shown that Adapter must implement SpecificRequest() as well." This is exactly because Adapter should not implement SpecificRequest(). Adapter should only implement Request(), using SpecificRequest()’s implementation defined in Adaptee.

Comment: 6. "Finally, GoF explains that Adapter is a subclass of Adaptee, which seems somewhat inconsistent." I agree, it might be confusing as GoF defines a subclass as inheriting both the interface and implementation of its superclass, whereas it is not the case for Adapter which inherits only the implementation of Adaptee.

Comment: 7. "What you call interface inheritance is ambiguous:" I agree, that is an excellent remark since interface inheritance (i.e. excluding implementation inheritance) indeed maps to four different situations: interface–interface (UML specialization), interface–class (UML interface realization), class–class, and class–interface.

Comment: 8. "What you call implementation and interface inheritance is ambiguous, since it is not clear if inheritance applies only to interface or also to implementation:" I meant both interface inheritance and implementation inheritance. This maps to a single situation so this one is not ambiguous: class–class (UML specialization).

Comment: 9. "If with implementation inheritance you were thinking of inheriting the implementation without inheriting the interface, i.e. private inheritance, then there is nothing special foreseen in UML" Yes, with implementation inheritance (i.e. excluding interface inheritance) I was thinking about private inheritance. This maps to a single situation: class–class (like Adaptee and Adapter).

Comment: 10. "Now to illustrate the graphical notation, here is the class Adapter pattern as described in GoF using the participant roles:" GoF does not mean that Adaptee is a pure interface nor that this interface is inherited, they mean explicitly that Adaptee is a concrete class and that it is privately inherited (cf. p. 144), that is they mean your second class diagram.

Comment: Using a generalization relationship between `Adapter` and `Adaptee` seems indeed the closest to private inheritance, since generalization is between two classifiers at the *same level* of abstraction (e.g. `Adapter` and `Adaptee` are both concrete classes), contrary to interface realization which is between two classifiers at *different levels* of abstraction (e.g. `Adapter` is a concrete class and `Target` is an abstract class).

Comment: However the inherited members of a generalization are fully inherited by default. Are you aware of a particular UML property or UML stereotype for specifying that only the *implementations* of `Adaptee`’s operations are inherited (and not their signatures)? Thanks for the nice diagrams by the way. Which tool did you use to draw them?

Comment: @Maggyero with inheritance you don’t put anything: the operations are inherited. You can {redefine} ii if you need to. For realization, nothing is inherited, because you only say you comply with the contract. There!sno way to tell you only get the implementation (see the SO link provided in my answer).

Comment: @Maggyero Sorry if I do not respond to your 10 points: there are some interesting thoughts and counter-thoughts. But SO isn’t meant to be a discussion forum. To summarize, my point is that GoF does not use consistently their own terminology. I am well aware of their design intents, having used them sufficiently in practice with enough variations. They could have worded the participant section in an unambiguous way, and they could have aligned graph and narrative. Anyway, the object adapter seems more interesting than the class adapter ;-)